# Javascript new Date() giving different outputs for different timezones

Tags: javascript

I have below code in my function

```
alert(date);
var result = new Date(date);      
alert(result);
```

Output as below

When I set my system time as India

```
2017-11-07
Tue Nov 07 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

When I set my System timezone as US & Canada

```
2017-11-07
Mon Nov 06 2017 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
```

What is the issue here and how can I fix this?

Comment: _“What is the issue here”_ - you tell us ... what issue do you have with this? Of course it can happen that you get a different day, if you switch to a different time zone ...

Comment: This is working exactly as it's supposed to work.

Comment: If you change your System's time, obviously your browser's JS engine will take that. There is nothing wrong.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue. Javascript is a client side language, so will tell you the client's date.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry but I think thats the intended behaviour.
If you convert this to a timestamp it will be the same.